# How to enable AWS managed key (aws/s3) as a AWS KMS key in S3 encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

How can i enable AWS managed key (aws/s3) as a AWS KMS key in S3 encryption using cloud formation?
I have the following code but i'm not sure if i should pass the key as an arn

```
MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
              KMSMasterKeyID: !GetAtt ARN?
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
```

Comment: It accepts a key ID or ARN. If you created the KMS Key in the same CF stack template and called it, for example,  `MyEncryptionKey` then just use `KMSMasterKeyID: !Ref MyEncryptionKey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use server-side encryption with S3-managed keys (SSE-S3) by modifying the Amazon S3 Bucket ServerSideEncryptionByDefault property to specify AES256 for SSEAlgorithm

```
MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256 
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
```

Comment: This will configure SSE-S3 rather than SSE-KMS, of course. That might be acceptable, but it offers less control over keys, access, and auditing.

Comment: I misunderstood his question because I saw aws/S3 and assumed he wanted to use the AWS S3 managed keys.